# Field "to" must be a JSON string ,FCM error

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending notification using FCM and php to android device shows the following error

```
"Field \"to\" must be a JSON string: [\"*****DEVICE TOKEN******\"]\n"
```

My input format is

```
{
    "to": [
        "DEVICE TOKEN"
    ],
    "data": {
        "title": "Tp App",
        "message": "Hai, this is my first fire base message",
        "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/minion.jpg"

    }
}
```

I know this is already asked questions.But I tried those solutions but didn't worked for me like "registraion_ids" changed to "to".
Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: use a website like jsonlint.com to check if you have valid JSON.. and it will also show you the error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an array to your `to` parameter, change it as

```
"to":"DEVICE TOKEN"
```

Comment: Can you provide the correct full format for message for single and multicast . So I can write code for that format

Comment: @RahulKR just replace `"to": ["DEVICE TOKEN"],` to one of the above syntax in your input

Comment: Thanks.Now it shows success 1, but message not getting at device side.Any idea?

Comment: For multiple device?, Like this ? `"to":"token1,token2,token3"`